# swift: How to show the saved image from my local Directory into Custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Here I have implemented a Custom cell:

```
  var imagePath = ""



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Static Cell will be shown in first row
        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell: ProfilePictureTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfilePictureTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ProfilePictureTableViewCell)!

            cell.backgroundColor = ClientConfiguration.primaryUIColor()
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            cell.profilePicture.userInteractionEnabled = true
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProfileTableViewController.ProfilePicTapped))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            cell.profilePicture.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            if(self.imagePath.length > 0)
            {
            cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.imagePath)
            }
            else{
                cell.profilePicture.image = self.setProfilePicture
            }
            return cell
        }
```

This cell have a UIImageView as profilePicture and on click of this view i can change the profile picture. This is used to load the pictures:

```
  func ProfilePicTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("Edit Profile Picture Clicked")

    profilePictureImage.allowsEditing = false
    profilePictureImage.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(profilePictureImage, animated: false, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]
    if let referenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL, pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {



        ALAssetsLibrary().assetForURL(referenceUrl, resultBlock: { asset in

            let fileName = asset.defaultRepresentation().filename()
            //do whatever with your file name
            let nameModel = DefaultNameModel()

            nameModel.value = fileName

            let referenceUrlToString : String = String(referenceUrl)
            let filePath = "\(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])/\(fileName)"
            self.imagePath = filePath
            let imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)! as NSData
            imageData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

            self.setProfilePicture = pickedImage
```

I have successfully written to my directory and I can even find the photos in local folder. Now I want to put the photo that I uploaded photo in cell that have UIImageView as profilePicture. How can I achieve this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload your first row, but for that first declare one instance property of type `UIImage?` with your controller and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` assign that `image` instance to your `profileImageView`, after that in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` set the selected image to this instance and simply reload the first row of your `tableView`.

```
var profileImage: UIImage?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Static Cell will be shown in first row
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell: ProfilePictureTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfilePictureTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ProfilePictureTableViewCell)!

        //Your other setting code for ProfilePictureTableViewCell

        //Set the image
        cell.profilePicture.image = self.profileImage

        return cell
    }
```

Now in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` set the image to `profileImage` ad reload the first row of your first section.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let referenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL, pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            //Code for saving image in document directory

            //Now set the selected image to profileImage and reload the first cell
            self.profileImage = pickedImage 
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

**Edit:** You can save the imagePath in `NSUserDefaults` while saving image in `DocumentDirectory` after that on `viewDidLoad` of your current controller simply check the `imagePath` is exist with `UserDefaults` if it is exists then use it to get the image from that path and assign it to the `profileImage` property. So first save the image in userDefault like this when you are saving image in documentDirectory.

```
 let imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)! as NSData
 imageData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
 //Save path in user defaults
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(filePath, forKey: "profileImagePath")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Now in viewDidLoad simply check that path is exists with the key or not.

```
if let path = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("profileImagePath") {
      self.profileImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.imagePath)
 }
```

**Note:** In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set image simply using single line `cell.profilePicture.image = self.profileImage`.

Comment: but this works only when i am outside the application.And when i re run the appplication it disappears and i cannot see anything in my profile picture

Comment: i have used..if(self.imagePath.length > 0)
            {
            cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.imagePath)
            }

Comment: this is the thing i have added...to show the profile picture

Comment: i canot see the previous photo after i login again..??

Comment: @Niroj imagePath is obviously empty, when you load that controller again you need to use UserDefaults, check my edited answer once agin for that.

Comment: @Niroj Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to configure the cell :

```
func configureCell ( cell : ProfilePictureTableViewCell, imageName : String){

    let path: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: imageName, ofType: "png", inDirectory: "DirectoryName/Images")
    let imageAtPath = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    cell.imageView?.image = imageAtPath
}
```

Here, "ProfilePictureTableViewCell" is sample UITableView  custom cell.

Call this method from :

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// Static Cell will be shown in first row
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    let cell: ProfilePictureTableViewCell =   (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfilePictureTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? ProfilePictureTableViewCell)!


    configureCell(cell: cell, imageName: "Pass Image Name") // You can change the paramets to the function as per your requirement

    return cell
}
```